# my code throws java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package threads;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class text implements Runnable {
    static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        testts();
        new Thread(new text()).start();

    }

    static void testts() {
        lock.lock();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lock.unlock();

        System.out.println("un-locked");
    }
}
```

throws

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:127)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:431)
    at threads.text.run(text.java:28)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Why do you think it **shouldn't** throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException`?

Answer (score 3):

The [javadoc of `ReentrantLock#unlock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock--) states

> If the current thread is not the holder of this lock then
>   `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown.

Your new thread does not own the lock, the main thread does. As such, when the new thread tries to unlock the lock which it doesn't hold, an exception is thrown.